# How to upload data to Cloudsearch programmatically .Net

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I am attempting to use Cloudsearch in lieu of SQL-based full-text indexing.  However, I have had little luck thus far.  Their API documentation is just horrendous, with almost no examples and no mention of using the SDK to do it.  All they provide are some shoddy command line scripts.

My use-case is that I am decompiling an ALD file and need to store the resulting text data up there.  The only listed methods involve using the command line or the web console, which won't do, seeing as I have tens of thousands of documents to manage.  Surely there is a way I can pass it an index and some text data via the C# SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Comb wrapper to handle the uploading, as it handles everything pretty handily in .NET.  Pretty sure it uses the methods enumerated by dotcomly under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, there is not much sample code and I am not a C# programmer so I won't really try to code it but in an effort to get you in the right direction it seems you just need to instantiate an `UploadDocumentsRequest` object, populate the `Documents` property then pass it to `AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient.UploadDocuments`.

Their documentation to upload is http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html

The request is documented here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CloudSearchDomain/TCloudSearchDomainUploadDocumentsRequest.html